# How to set ItemsSource of a combobox from a Observablecollection

Tags: c#, combobox, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml, observablecollection

Hi i'm working on a WinRT project with the MVVM-Light framework.
I have a listview wich ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection on my ViewModel.
The objects (ClassOne) in this ObservableCollection have a field which is an ObservableCollection itself.
In the Listview i have ComboBoxes who's itemsSource i would like to bind to the second ObservableCollection (This is the field in the other observablecollection).
The second ObservableCollection gets  dynamicaly filled in the ViewModel of my View.

My Xaml code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOne}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
 <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataCollectionOne}"></TextBlock>                        
     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CorrespondingViewModel.CollectionOne.CollectionTwo, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataCollectionTwo}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ComboBox> 
</StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What i'm trying to do is:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CorrespondingViewModel.CollectionOne.CollectionTwo, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

But this isn't working.

This is my Property of CollectionOne on the ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<ClassOne> _collectionOne;
    public ObservableCollection<ClassOne> CollectionOne
    {
        get { return _collectionOne;; }
        set
        {
            if (_collectionOne; == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _collectionOne; = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CollectionOne);
        }
    }
```

This is the class inside the ObservableCollection(ClassOne):

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public string DataCollectionOne{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ClassTwo> CollectionTwo{ get; set; }
}
```

Class Two just contains a String Property.

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    public string DataCollectionTwo{ get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that in a test project,

you can simply exchange your code

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CorrespondingViewModel.CollectionOne.CollectionTwo, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

with

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionTwo}">
```

in my test project that works fine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, But the field i need is inside CollectionTwo who is inside CollectionOne. So the normal Binding doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I made the test project exactly with your code and exchanged just what i've posted above: the binding <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataCollectionTwo}"/> does work for me and this property is inside CollectionTwo or not?

Comment: Thanks, the first time i had a mistake in my viewmodel, your method does work.